# Firing a Method Directly from Input in React

Tags: html, reactjs

Is there a way to dispatch an action directly from an input tag?

```
             <input
              className="text"
              required
              onChange={this.props.updateInput.bind(this,"title",e.target.value)}
              value={this.props.title}
            />
```

I'm having an issue where e.target.value is no recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new inlined arrow function that passes along the `value` from the event.

```
<input
  className="text"
  required
  onChange={e => this.props.updateInput("title", e.target.value)}
  value={this.props.title}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use @Tholle's advise then you should use `updateInput` function like that:

```
updateInput(title, value) {
    console.log( title, value );
}
```

I don't know why you need "title" string as a variable there, but if your intent is changing a `title` state where resides in a parent from your child component here is an example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
  }
  updateInput = title => {
    this.setState( { title });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input title={this.state.title} onChange={this.updateInput} />
        <br />
        Title is: {this.state.title}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Input = (props) => {
  const handleInput = e =>
    props.onChange(e.target.value)
  return (
    <input
      className="text"
      required
      onChange={handleInput}
      value={props.title}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```